# Smoothly rotate a sphere

Tags: matlab, rotation

While drawing a simple unit sphere, I want to rotate it continuously and smoothly.

If we use camorbit or camroll, it actually, rotates then takes a pause, which is not a smooth and continuous rotation.

Any suggestions how to achieve that,

Example:

a simple sphere

```
figure
sphere
axis equal
for i = 1: 100
    camorbit(-5, 0);
    % pause(0.01);
    drawnow;
end
```

This is a pretty simple example, however if we use a large data set like wrapping an image data on this sphere and rotate along its axis, it takes some time to render it.
I tired using OpenGL or auto renderer as well as pause (0.01), still it didn't make much difference.

The figure looks like it stops for a while and then moves to the next, which clearly isn't a continuous spherical rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This works decently for me:

```
figure
sphere
axis equal
axis off
axis vis3d
h_plot = gca;
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'zbuffer')
while ishandle(h_plot)
    camorbit(-5, 0);
    drawnow;
end
```